# Proving that if prime p>3 divides a^2 + 12, then p is congruent 2(mod 3)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

> Prove that if prime $p>3$ divides $a^2 + 12$, then $p$ is congruent $2\pmod 3$.

I tried splitting (-12/P) to (-1/P) * (3/P) and solving 4 different cases to find when (-12/P) = 1, but I got that p is congruent to 1(mod 3). What's wrong?

Comment: What is $a$?  If $a=1$, then $a^2+12=13$, which is $1$ mod $3$.

Comment: For $a = 3$, $a^2 + 12 = 21 = 7 \cdot 3 \quad 7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: Similar for $a=5$.  In fact, $\left(\dfrac {-3}p\right)=1$ if $p\equiv1\pmod3$, and $\left(\dfrac {-3}p\right)=-1$ if $p\equiv2\pmod3$

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you are correct and the statement is wrong,

because $\left(\dfrac{-12}p\right)=\left(\dfrac4p\right)\left(\dfrac{-3}p\right)=\left(\dfrac {-3}p\right)$, [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B13) is $1$ if $p\equiv1\pmod3$,

and $ -1$ if $p\equiv2\pmod3.$